# connectionDidFinishLoading when release that object

Tags: objective-c, xcode, request, web

I hace multiples object that request a file to a server, all work great but if i want to release that objet early, the dealloc is called , the data still comming and inside the connectionDidFinishLoading when i use for example a uilabel to save the data the app crash with a bad acces error. There are any solution? 
If i wait to all tha data cames, and release the object the  app work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about `NSURLConnection` look at the method

```
- (void)cancel
```

Place this at the beginning of your `dealloc

The [NSURLConnection docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) say:

> After this method is called, the connection’s delegate no longer receives any messages for the connection. If you want to reattempt the connection, you should create a new connection object.

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to release the object early, so I assume you are not using ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) and hence you are not coding iOS 5.0.

Instead of releasing the object, autorelease the object. The system will dealloc the delegate as soon as the delegate is no longer needed. Also, don't forget to cancel you connection.